# How to get the max length of the record size of a dataframe effectively

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

How to know the size of longest record (row) of a dataset in bytes.

I have quite a big dataframe with variable length of record (row) and I want to know the length of the row with largest payload.

It has millions\billions of rows, so I want to know a way which is effective and won't affect the performance.

I have DataFrameWriter as an input.

Comment: One correction above: I have DataFrameWriter<Row> or Dataset<Row> as an input.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code.

```
scala> import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

scala> val bytes = udf((length:Long) => FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(length)) // To disply human readable size.
bytes: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,StringType,Some(List(LongType)))

scala> df
.withColumn("size",length(to_json(struct($"*"))))
.orderBy($"size".desc)
.select(bytes($"size").as("size_in_bytes"))
.show(10,false)
+-------------+
|size_in_bytes|
+-------------+
|49 KB        |
|49 KB        |
|49 KB        |
|48 KB        |
|48 KB        |
|48 KB        |
|43 KB        |
|43 KB        |
|43 KB        |
|42 KB        |
+-------------+
only showing top 10 rows


scala> df
.withColumn("size",length(to_json(struct($"*"))))
.orderBy($"size".desc)
.select($"size".as("size_in_bytes"))
.show(10,false)// Without UDF.
+-------------+
|size_in_bytes|
+-------------+
|50223        |
|50219        |
|50199        |
|50079        |
|50079        |
|50027        |
|44536        |
|44488        |
|44486        |
|43836        |
+-------------+
only showing top 10 rows


scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is helpful-

**`bit_length`**

```scala
val df = Seq((1, 2, "hi", "hello")).toDF()

    df.selectExpr("max(bit_length(concat_ws('', *)))/8 as bytes")
      .show(false)
    /**
      * +-----+
      * |bytes|
      * +-----+
      * |9.0  |
      * +-----+
      */
```